# Laravel 5.7 "Class name must be a valid object or a string"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy realizando un crud, y al llegar a la parte de la modificacion tengo el siguiente problema,
anteriormente ya habia realizado otros proyectos y en esta parte todo funcionaba bien, el problema sale porque las id´s de las tablas siempre eran simples, pero en este caso las id´s son distintas ejemplo

id_tipoproducto

A la hora de usar el metodo Find() se enfoca solo en la llave primaria (id) y este metodo no me funciona, asi que busque otro porque tambien lo uso para el metodo de eliminar y es el siguiente

```
    $tipo_producto->tipo_producto::whereRaw('id_tipoproducto = id_tipoproducto', [$id_tipoproducto])->get();
```

el problema esta en que a la hora de dar submit al formulario me regresa el siguiente error:

> **"Class name must be a valid object or a string"**

les muestro el codigo que estoy usando para modificar mi registro.

```
public function update(Request $request, tipo_producto $tipo_producto)
{
$id_tipoproducto = $request->id_tipoproducto;
$tipo_producto->tipo_producto::whereRaw('id_tipoproducto = id_tipoproducto', [$id_tipoproducto])->get();
//$tipo_producto= tipo_producto::find($id_tipoproduto);
$tipo_producto->tipo = $request ['tipo'];
$tipo_producto->update();
return redirect('tipop'); 
}
```

Anexo la estructura de mi modelo y de mi tabla

```
  <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tipo_producto extends Model
{
    protected $table="tipo_producto";
    protected $fillable=['id_tipoproducto','tipo'];
}
```

[image: Tabla con la que estoy trabajando]

y aqui el error que me salta si intento usar el metodo find()
[image: Error al usar Find]

Comment: Cuando utilizo find, me manda un error de base de datos ya que en la tabla busca el registro id, en lugar de buscar el id_tipoproducto, tuve que usar el otro metodo para que me buscara el campo correcto

Comment: ah, no no es ninguna llave foranea, es algo confuso, el id_tipotabla es mi llave primaria, pero laravel al usar la funcion Find() busca por defecto solo un id simple, de hecho en el modelo tambien declare mi llave primaria, pero me sigue saltando el mismo error, facilmente podria reemplazar el id primario con solo id, pero en la escuela me piden que declare los id´s haciendo referencia a la tabla :/

Comment: listo ya lo añadi, este problema lo tuve desde proyectos anteriores, pero evitaba todo dejando las llaves primarias de todas mis tablas en id

Comment: si, solo es la actualizacion del campo ya que el envio de la informacion del index a la vista ya esta, el error viene cuando una ves hecho los cambios en el registro le doy a submit

Comment: Uso laravel 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atendamos algunas observaciones:

- No estás declarando la propiedad necesaria para *decirle a Eloquent* que tu llave primaria tiene un nombre distinto al esperado, [entonces va así](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions):

  ```
  protected $primaryKey = 'id_tipoprpoducto';
  ```
- Además de lo anterior, estas filtrando por la llave primaria por lo tanto se me hace innecesario (no es que esté mal) inyectes al modelo y un objeto (*pues al hacer esto considero que sería mas útil por ejemplo si estuvieras trabajando con [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding)*)

Entonces nuestra actualización pudiera quedar así:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $elementoAModificar = tipo_producto::findOrFail($id);
    $elementoAModificar->tipo = $request->tipo;
    $elementoAModificar->save();
}
```

Lo que [hacemos es](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#updates):

- Filtrar del modelo `tipo_producto`
- Indicar que a la propiedad `tipo` le asignamos el valor de `tipo` que nos llega por el request
- Guadar los cambios hechos

Comment: Me funciono a la perfeccion!, ya no me da el error de la classe y tampoco del find, muchisimas gracias!!